# Writing swift dictionary to file

Tags: swift, dictionary, nsdictionary, plist

There are limitations with writing NSDictionaries into files in swift. Based on what I have learned from api docs and [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8713846/why-nsmutabledictionary-dont-want-write-to-file?answertab=active#tab-top), key types should be NSString, and value types also should be NSx type, and Int, String, and other swift types might not work. 
The question is that if I have a dictionary like: `Dictionary<Int, Dictionary<Int, MyOwnType>>`, how can I write/read it to/from a plist file in swift?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Anyway, when you want to store `MyOwnType` to file, `MyOwnType` must be a subclass of `NSObject` and conforms to `NSCoding` protocol. like this:

```
class MyOwnType: NSObject, NSCoding {

    var name: String

    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        name = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("name") as? String ?? ""
    }

    func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {
        aCoder.encodeObject(name, forKey: "name")
    }
}
```

Then, here is the `Dictionary`:

```
var dict = [Int : [Int : MyOwnType]]()
dict[1] = [
    1: MyOwnType(name: "foobar"),
    2: MyOwnType(name: "bazqux")
]
```

So, here comes your question:

> Writing swift dictionary to file

You can use `NSKeyedArchiver` to write, and `NSKeyedUnarchiver` to read:

```
func getFileURL(fileName: String) -> NSURL {
    let manager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
    let dirURL = manager.URLForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomain: .UserDomainMask, appropriateForURL: nil, create: false, error: nil)
    return dirURL!.URLByAppendingPathComponent(fileName)
}

let filePath = getFileURL("data.dat").path!

// write to file
NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(dict, toFile: filePath)

// read from file
let dict2 = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithFile(filePath) as [Int : [Int : MyOwnType]]

// here `dict2` is a copy of `dict`
```

But in the body of your question:

> how can I write/read it to/from a **plist** file in swift?

In fact, `NSKeyedArchiver` [format is binary plist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2447886/what-format-does-nskeyedarchiver-save). But if you want that dictionary **as a value of plist**, you can serialize `Dictionary` to `NSData` with `NSKeyedArchiver`:

```
// archive to data
let dat:NSData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(dict)

// unarchive from data
let dict2 = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(data) as [Int : [Int : MyOwnType]]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed and great response. I am new to swift and iOS dev and it helped me to understand related stuff too :)

Comment: this writes a lot of entities to the plist

Answer (score 1):

Response for Swift 5

```
private func getFileURL(fileName: String) throws -> URL {
        let manager = FileManager.default
        let dirURL = try manager.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
        return dirURL.appendingPathComponent(fileName)
 }

 if let filePath = try? getFileURL(fileName: "data.dat").path {
        NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(data, toFile: filePath)
 }
```