# Cache Array of Custom Objects in Swift3

Tags: ios, swift, caching, swift3, persistence

I need to persist an array of custom objects from session to session for a user. The array will be filled with 1-14 fairly simple and lightweight custom swift objects like so:

```
[Obj1, Obj2, Obj3]
```

What I want to do is when `viewWillDisappear` is called, persist this data so that when the user comes back to the screen, I can use these exact objects again. What is the best way to do this? I've looked into using core data, but I don't want to setup a data model for these objects, just store them as is without any relationships or anything.

Please note that the app makes use of a very computationally taxing algorithm, of which these objects play a central role. As such, I need to keep these objects as light as possible. Therefore, I don't want to make the objects conform to NSCoding as it isn't necessary to the central role of the object

Comment: "Please note that for various reasons these objects are not suitable to be stored in NSUserdefaults." I'd be interested to hear those, because that would be my go-to solution

Comment: You could use NSCoding + NSKeyedArchiver

Comment: Use `NSCoding`, see a similar approach here: [Writing swift dictionary to file](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27197658/2415822)

Comment: @Alexander. In answer to your question, the app makes use of a very computationally taxing algorithm, of which these objects play a central role. As such, I need to keep these objects as light as possible. Therefore, I don't want to make the objects conform to NSCoding as it isn't necessary to the central role of the object.

Comment: If you don't want to make the objects conform to `NSCoding` then I think you fail to grasp the concept of [serialization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization).  `NSCoding` is how that works on iOS.  Or make a storage wrapper class that conforms to `NSCoding` which holds the array.

Comment: @JamesStonehill You can make a NSCoding subclass that's used solely for storage, and make your current lightweight Swift objects have an initializer that takes the container object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If making your class an Objective-C class that conforms to `NSCoding` proves to actually have a substantial performance impact (I'm skeptical), then you can make a second container that subclasses `NSCoding` that's used solely for storage. Add an initializer to your current lightweight Swift class/struct that initializes the instance from this container object, and vice versa. Any time you need to serialize/deserialize, you just use this container object as an intermediate.

This buys you the functionality at minimal cost when reading/writing, but leaves regular usage performance unaffected.

Comment: How would adding another layer on top of `NSCoding` improve performance? I'm not sure I understand why one would do that.

Comment: @sbooth Objective C classes always use dynamic dispatch. The compiler can't inline any methods, trim unused code, or do any optimizations that require looking "into" method calls.

Comment: @sbooth Thus, it maybe beneficial to take a hit any time an object is serialized/deserialized due to this extra middleman logic, but then benefit from faster performance during the rest of the time

Answer (score 0):

If you can make the object a subclass of NSObject then you can have it conform to NSCoding and use NSKeyedArchiver and NSKeyedUnarchiver  to serialize and deserialize your objects.

Comment: See my reply to Alexander above.